# My view object 'has no attribute' {my attribute} in Django

Tags: django

**Background**

I'm trying to load a custom url (e.g. [www.mysite.com/order-2523432](http://www.mysite.com/order-2523432)) that will show a user  details about their order.

**Problem**

I am trying to use the method order_id in my models.py in order to get the correct url. The problem is that I am getting the error:

```
'OrderDetailView' object has no attribute 'order_id'
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get order_id to work?

**My views.py:**

```
class OrderDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Orders
    template_name = "customer/orders.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context["orders"] = get_orders(self)
        except RequestException as e:
            logger.exception(e)
        return context
```

**My utils.py:**

```
def get_orders(orders):
    url = f"mysite.com/customer/{orders.order_id}"
    method = "GET"
    content_type = "application/json"
    header = Sender(
        credentials etc
    ).request_header
    response = requests.request(
        headers etc
    )
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()
```

**My models.py:**

```
class Orders(CustomModel):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

    @property
    def order_id(self):
        return f"order-{self.table_name}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("order:edit", args=(self.id,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `self.object` or `context['object']` or `get_object()` instead of passing self 
please try this:

```
class OrderDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Orders
    template_name = "customer/orders.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context["orders"] = get_orders(context['object'])
        except RequestException as e:
            logger.exception(e)
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you Eisa! self.object worked perfectly, I understand why now